# Annotate in Microsoft teams

Tags: macos, microsoft-teams, annotate, screensharing, teamwork-projects

as we all working remotely these days, I have an issue with drawing on the screen when someone shares the screen with teams Microsoft.
I found some ideas that I can use zoomIt, is there anything else for helping me to draw in the screen sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Teams does not Allow drawing on screen share. Could you please raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)?

Answer (score 0):

Annotation while screen sharing is now available in Microsoft Teams
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-annotation-while-sharing-your-screen-in-teams-876ba527-7112-437e-b410-5aec7363c473

Comment: This feature doesn't exist on a mac. any idea why?